# c# using alert box. how to prevent even from happing

Tags: c#, javascript, mysql, alert

On button click my input data is sent of to my MySQL server, if the Data is input in wrong in this case if the two drop down list selections do not mathc you get a message sayings its wrong.
problem is the data is still sent to my database.
how can i prevent this?

```
if (!ddlcountry.SelectedItem.ToString().Equals(ddlcountry_Res.SelectedItem.ToString()))
        {
            Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>alert('You are trying to adoped a pet from anouther country !!');</script>");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>alert('Congratulations for adopting a pet.');</script>");
        }
```

My apologies guys, a more comprehensive explanation.

My problem is I have in my on click event a list of insert statements that insert data from text boxes and drop down lists and more, then this if else statement is underneath to check that two drop down selections match.
Problem begin the data input via the text boxes is still getting through to the database, so I would like to stop the data begin sent to the database if the two drop downs do not match.

Comment: Horribly vague question. Why not validate the data BEFORE you actually write it to the database?

Comment: @Beep: you can return from the invalid case.

Comment: You will need to show more code. My guess is that you're saving to the database after the else {} of the if. Then you would two options. 1. Write return after the Response.Write of the if{}. 2. Write the data save logic in the else {} .

Answer (score 1):

**Problem :** if i understand it correctly you have written statements after `if-else {}` block which are getting `executed` irrespective of the `situation` `(true or false).`

**Solution:**  if that is the case you should `reconsider` your logic, as you should `come out` from the executing `database` queries if your `expression/condition` `evaluates` to `false`.

you can use `return` keyword to return from the `invalid` case. 
if you `return` from invalid case further statements( `after return` ) won't get executed.

try this:

```
          if (!ddlcountry.SelectedItem.ToString().Equals(ddlcountry_Res.SelectedItem.ToString()))
            {
                Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>alert('You are trying to adoped a pet from anouther country !!');</script>");
                return;//return if you don't want to execute further statements
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>alert('Congratulations for adopting a pet.');</script>");
            }
```

Comment: the data is before the if else blocks.